# how to script animation fcurve made autoclamped

Tags: python

How can I script action made by setting keyframe handle type for bezier f-curve in Graph Editor to AUTO_CLAMPED?

```
o = bpy.data.objects['jet-1.1']
fc = o.animation_data.action.fcurves[1]  # Y Euler Rotaion
kfs = fc.keyframe_points
for frame, value in DATA:
    kf = kfs.insert(frame, value, {'FAST'})
    kf.interpolation = 'BEZIER'
    kf.handle_left_type = 'AUTO_CLAMPED'
    kf.handle_right_type = 'AUTO_CLAMPED'
```

When I try to do it this way, curve doesn't get smoothed. How can it be achived?

This picture shows the result of the script from above:
[image]

But I want to have the result like this:
[image]

Comment: try `fc.update()` after you inserted the keyframes

Comment: thank you very much, it works! sorry for being accidently unable to upvote your comment.